# Not getting proper response from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp form for creating a so called NonCIC Account. I have written the jsp code, the javascript function, method in the controller class and in the DAOImpl class. But, whenever I click on the Create button, despite entering values in the text fields, I am getting the error message : "Please provide the Account Name, Department Name and Department Number." I am not getting what's wrong here. Please help.

I have the following JSP code :

```
<div id="div2" class="hide">
    <label for="nonCICAccountName">Account Name:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nonCICAccountName" id="nonCICAccountName" /> <br /> 
    <label for="country">Country:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="country" id="country" /> <br /> 
    <label for="countryNumber">Country Number:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="countryNumber" id="countryNumber" /> <br />
    <label for="locationName">Location Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="locationName" id="locationName" /> <br />
    <label for="locationNumber">Location Number:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="locationNumber" id="locationNumber" /> <br />
    <label for="departmentName">Department Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="departmentName" id="departmentName" /> <br />
    <label for="departmentNumber">Department Number:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="departmentNumber" id="departmentNumber" /> <br />
    <label for="division">Division:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="division" id="division" /> <br />
    <label for="major">Major:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="major" id="major" /> <br />
    <label for="minor">Minor:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="minor" id="minor" /> <br />
    <label for="subminor">Subminor:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="subminor" id="subminor" /> <br />
    <label for="leru">Leru:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="leru" id="leru" /> <br />
    <label for="task">Task:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" /> <br />
    <label for="approvingManager">Approving Manager:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="approvingManager" id="approvingManager" /> <br />
    <label for="financialApprover">Financial Approver:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="text" name="financialApprover" id="financialApprover" /> <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Create NonCIC Account" onclick="createNonCICAccount();">
    <input type="button" value="Search Account" onclick="searchNonCICAccount();">
</div>
```

Following is the function createNonCICAccount() :

```
function createNonCICAccount() {

var accountName = document.getElementById("nonCICAccountName").value;
var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
var countryNumber = document.getElementById("countryNumber").value;
var locationName = document.getElementById("locationName").value;
var locationNumber = document.getElementById("locationNumber").value;

var departmentName = document.getElementById("departmentName").value;
var departmentNumber = document.getElementById("departmentNumber").value;
var division = document.getElementById("division").value;

var major = document.getElementById("major").value;
var minor = document.getElementById("minor").value;
var subminor = document.getElementById("subminor").value;
var leru = document.getElementById("leru").value;
var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
var approvingManager = document.getElementById("approvingManager").value;
var financialApprover = document.getElementById("financialApprover").value;
 
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "NonCICAccountController",  
        data: {"action":"createNonCICAccount",
        "nonCICAccountName":accountName,"country":country,"countryNumber":countryNumber,"locationName":locationName,"locationNumber":locationNumber,"departmentName":departmentName,"departmentmentNumber":departmentNumber,"division":division,"major":major,"minor":minor,
            "subminor":subminor,"leru":leru,"task":task,"approvingManager":approvingManager,"financialApprover":financialApprover},  
        success: function(data,jqXHR){  
            $("#accMessageDiv").html(data);
            reset();
        }, 
        error: function(data,jqXHR){  
            $("#accMessageDiv").html(data);
        }, 
        beforeSend: function() {
                // setting a timeout
        },
        complete: function() {
        }
      }); 
 }
```

Following is the NonCICAccount class :

```
package com.coetool.servlet.model;

public class NonCICAccount {

private int accountId;
private String accountName;
private String country;
private int countryNumber;
private String locationName;
private String locationNumber;
private String departmentName;
private String departmentNumber;
private String division;
private int major;
private int minor;
private int subminor;
private String leru;
private int task;
private String approvingManager;
private String financialApprover;

public NonCICAccount() {}

public NonCICAccount(int accountId, String accountName, String country,int countryNumber,String locationName,String locationNumber,String departmentName,String departmentNumber,String division,int major, int minor,
        int subminor,String leru,int task,String approvingManager,String financialApprover)
{
    this.accountId=accountId;
    this.accountName=accountName;
    this.country = country;
    this.countryNumber = countryNumber;
    this.locationName = locationName;
    this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.departmentNumber = departmentNumber;
    this.division = division;
    this.major = major;
    this.minor = minor;
    this.subminor = subminor;
    this.leru = leru;
    this.task = task;
    this.approvingManager = approvingManager;
    this.financialApprover = financialApprover;
}

public int getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
}

public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public int getCountryNumber() {
    return countryNumber;
}

public void setCountryNumber(int countryNumber) {
    this.countryNumber = countryNumber;
}

public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}

public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
    this.locationName = locationName;
}

public String getLocationNumber() {
    return locationNumber;
}

public void setLocationNumber(String locationNumber) {
    this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
}

public String getDepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public String getDepartmentNumber() {
    return departmentNumber;
}

public void setDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {
    this.departmentNumber = departmentNumber;
}

public String getDivision() {
    return division;
}

public void setDivision(String division) {
    this.division = division;
}

public int getMajor() {
    return major;
}

public void setMajor(int major) {
    this.major = major;
}

public int getMinor() {
    return minor;
}

public void setMinor(int minor) {
    this.minor = minor;
}

public int getSubminor() {
    return subminor;
}

public void setSubminor(int subminor) {
    this.subminor = subminor;
}

public String getLeru() {
    return leru;
}

public void setLeru(String leru) {
    this.leru = leru;
}

public int getTask() {
    return task;
}

public void setTask(int task) {
    this.task = task;
}

public String getApprovingManager() {
    return approvingManager;
}

public void setApprovingManager(String approvingManager) {
    this.approvingManager = approvingManager;
}

public String getFinancialApprover() {
    return financialApprover;
}

public void setFinancialApprover(String financialApprover) {
    this.financialApprover = financialApprover;
}
}
```

Following is the createNonCICAccount method in the NonCICAccountController class :

```
 protected void createNonCICAccount(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    String error;
    
    NonCICAccount account = new NonCICAccount();
    
    account = fillAttributes(account, request);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    NonCICAccountDAO accountDAO = new NonCICAccountDAOImpl();
    NonCICAccount accountToBeFetched = null;

    int result=0;
    try {
        if(account.getAccountName() != null && account.getDepartmentName() != null && account.getDepartmentNumber() !=null)
        { 
             accountToBeFetched = accountDAO.getNonCICAccountDetailsWithAccountNameAndDepartmentNumber(account);
            if(accountToBeFetched== null)
                result = accountDAO.createNonCICAccount(account);
            
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     if (account.getAccountName() == null || account.getDepartmentName() == null || account.getDepartmentNumber() == null ) {
        error = "Please provide the Account Name, Department Name and Department Number.";
        
        
        out.write("<p style='color:red;'>"+error+"</p>");
    }
    else if(accountToBeFetched != null && (account.getAccountName() != null || account.getDepartmentName() != null || account.getDepartmentNumber() != null ))
    {
            error = "Account already exist with given Account Name, Department Name and Department Number.";
            out.write("<p style='color:red;'>"+error+"</p>");
    }
     else {
        String msg = "Account  :"+account.getAccountName() + "  successfully added. ";
        out.write("<p style='color:blue;'>"+msg+"</p>");
        /*session.setAttribute("message", msg);
        session.removeAttribute("error");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");*/
    }

}
```

Following is the fillAttributes method in the NonCICAccountController class :

```
 private NonCICAccount fillAttributes(NonCICAccount account,HttpServletRequest request)
{
    
    account.setAccountName(checkNull(request.getParameter("nonCICAccountName")));
    account.setCountry(checkNull(request.getParameter("country")));
    account.setCountryNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("countryNumber")));
    account.setLocationName(checkNull(request.getParameter("locationName")));
    account.setLocationNumber(checkNull(request.getParameter("locationNumber")));
    account.setDepartmentName(checkNull(request.getParameter("departmentName")));
    account.setDepartmentNumber(checkNull(request.getParameter("departmentNumber")));
    account.setDivision(checkNull(request.getParameter("division")));
    account.setMajor(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("major")));
    account.setMinor(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("minor")));
    account.setSubminor(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subminor")));
    account.setLeru(checkNull(request.getParameter("leru")));
    account.setTask(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("task")));
    account.setApprovingManager(checkNull(request.getParameter("approvingManager")));
    account.setFinancialApprover(checkNull(request.getParameter("financialApprover")));
    
    return account;
}
```

Following is the checkNull method :

```
 private String checkNull(String input)
{
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(input))
        return input;
    else
        return null;
            
}
```

Following is the createNonCICAccount method in the NonCICAccountDAOImpl class :

```
 public int createNonCICAccount(NonCICAccount account) throws SQLException {
    int result = 0;
    try {

        // dbConnection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        
        pStmt.setString(1, account.getAccountName());
        pStmt.setString(2, account.getCountry());
        pStmt.setInt(3, account.getCountryNumber());
        pStmt.setString(4, account.getLocationName());
        pStmt.setString(5, account.getLocationNumber());
        pStmt.setString(6, account.getDepartmentName());
        pStmt.setString(7, account.getDepartmentNumber());
        pStmt.setString(8, account.getDivision());
        pStmt.setInt(9, account.getMajor());
        pStmt.setInt(10, account.getMinor());
        pStmt.setInt(11, account.getSubminor());
        pStmt.setString(12, account.getLeru());
        pStmt.setInt(13, account.getTask());
        pStmt.setString(14, account.getApprovingManager());
        pStmt.setString(15, account.getFinancialApprover());
        
        result = pStmt.executeUpdate();

        /*
         * rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys(); if(rs != null && rs.next()){
         * System.out.println("Generated Emp Id: "+rs.getInt(1)); }
         */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new SQLException(e);
    } finally {
        try {

            if (pStmt != null)
                pStmt.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Following is the SQL_INSERT query :

```
   INSERT INTO NonCICAccount      (accountName,country,countryNumber,locationName,locationNumber,departmentName,de     partmentNumber,division,major,minor,subminor,leru,task,approvingmanager,financialApprover) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Please help and advise.

Comment: I'd suggest that you attach a debugger to your Java process and take a look at what's happening.

Comment: what is the method "checkNull" doing? Please post code for it.

Comment: I have already attached a debugger and checked. But, unable to get a clue.

Comment: I have posted the code for the "checkNull" method. Please advise.